# How to re-use cookies with curl and php on the next request without cookiejar

Tags: php, curl, cookies, libcurl

I have multiple application nodes under a load-balancer which is making it problematic for me to save cookies on file as it might save on one node but then next request might point to the other node where the file doesn't exist.

This is the code I use to do the request which works fine on a single node but not on multiple ones:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    if ($this->proxy) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
    }
    if (!is_null($headers)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->settingsPath . $this->username . '-cookies.dat');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->settingsPath . $this->username . '-cookies.dat');

    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($post));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    }

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

So is there any other way I could grab the *"Set-Cookie"* headers directly, save them into a session and re-use them instead of using *COOKIEJAR* and *COOKIEFILE*?
I know there is *CURLOPT_COOKIE*, however my response header seems to have multiple "Set-Cookie" references and I don't know how to format them to use in *CURLOPT_COOKIE*.

Or at least is there a way to store the cookie files with *CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR* in a centralized storage server and read them back from there and how would I go on doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. restore cookie.dat from database, 2. do the request, 3. store cookie.dat to database. Or if you have a shared filemount on all servers(should be fast enough), just store the cookie.dat there

Comment: Why not implement session pinning on load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

store/load the cookies from a database. you can use the browser client's cookie session id as the db id (aka what you get from session_id()). also,  don't hardcode cookie locations, that's asking for trouble (what happens when 2 people load the same page with the same hardcoded cookie location at the same time? or what happens if you're on a read-only filesystem, where PHP doesn't have write-access?), just use tmpfile.

Comment: Thanks though that wouldn't be a big deal in my case as each cookie file is named uniquely for each user. I am currently storing it in a session and using that session to create a file for the next request, but I was hoping I could somehow use the session directly without the COOKIEFILE option.

Comment: @Galanx well, you can extract the cookies from curl, and set them manually with the CURLOPT_COOKIE option, no need for COOKIEFILE. extracting the cookies from curl isn't so easy tho